# Laravel SQL Server QueryException could not find driver in PHP file

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

In my Laravel when I am executing a simple select query to see if everything is working I am getting the error in my PHP 7.0.1 Laravel page.

```
QueryException
could not find driver
```

So in order to check everything I wrote simple PHP page without Laravel and I am able to connect to the same DB using the PHP function and this is returning the results means with respect to DB and PHP everything is fine.

```
<?php
    $servername     = "ABBDBDBBD\SQLEXPRESS";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"DB_NAME", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"PASSWORD");


if($connect)
{
    $search_query   =   "   SELECT TOP 15 * FROM TBL_CLIENT ";
    $result_query   =   sqlsrv_query($connect,$search_query);
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_query))
    {
        echo $row['CLIENT_MNEMONIC'];
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Not Connected";
}
?>
```

This is working fine so my guess is that PHP is working fine with the WAMP but something is not write with my Laravel or I am missing some small thing.
I changed my Composer PHP version from PHP 5.6 to 7.0.1 during the time I am getting this error.
Everything in Laravel was working fine when I was using PHP 5.6 but not sure what went wrong.

This is the complete error message in my PHP page.

```
(3/3) QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TBL_CLIENT
WHERE CLIENT_MNEMONIC LIKE 'ac%'
AND ACTIVE_IND = 1
ORDER BY CLIENT_MNEMONIC
)

in Connection.php line 647
at Connection->runQueryCallback(' SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TBL_CLIENT WHERE CLIENT_MNEMONIC LIKE \'ac%\' AND ACTIVE_IND = 1 ORDER BY CLIENT_MNEMONIC ', array(), object(Closure))
in Connection.php line 607
```

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes Windows 10, Laravel 5.4 and PHP 7.0.1.
Is there anything we need to do in Windows OS?
I have already set the Environment Variable to PHP 7.0.1 which Is present in the WAMP server.

Comment: My first guess would be that you have to enable the SQL Server driver in the `php.ini`. Can you compare the `php.ini` files of PHP 5.6 and 7.0?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I have enabled it. And installed the SQLSRV driver for windows 10. Its working fine for the above PHP code means that everything is fine from PHP.ini file because `while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result_query))
` function in that above PHP is executing

Comment: You need the PDO driver for Laravel: `php_pdo_sqlsrv_*`. Which driver are you using at the moment?

Comment: Related to following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261535/laravel-and-ms-sql-server-database-connection-is-throwing-the-error-3-3-query