# Laravel and MS SQL Server Database connection is throwing the error "(3/3) QueryException could not find driver"

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5, database-connection

`Guys, I tried lots of things mentioned in Stackoverflow and laracasts for this issue but none worked, hence posting this in hope of getting some answer or advice.` Also, most of the things provided belongs to MYSQL not for MS SQL.

I am using Windows 10 and using Laravel to connect to my Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express edition.

I have the .erv file as following:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=W1234567\SQLEXPRESS
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=My_Database_Name
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=My_Password
```

The given details are correct but when I am running a simple query I am getting following error message in my `Laravel Model`:

```
(3/3) QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM TBL_Data
WHERE ACTIVE_IND = 1
)
```

I have the WAMP running properly, I have added the `SQLSRV` file to my WAMP.

The entire thing was working fine, now I moved the code to different system there I am getting this error (Both the system has the same credentials only change is the Server name which I have changed) so the code should work properly as there are no changes done.

I tried checking the SQL Server TCP/IP port number in `SQL Server Configuration Manager` and changed it to 1433 still no luck.

I checked most of the answers here and they belong to PDO exception and asked people to uncomment the part `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` but in my case its SQL Server and normal wamp is working perfectly only seems to be problem with LARAVEL.

Can anyone provide the solutions for this?

`Edited part below with some more info:`

I checked if the credentials given are correct and if I am able to connect to db using a simple function in controller:
My Route: `Route::get('/Test', 'My_Controller@Test');`

My Controller:

```
public function Test(Request $request)
{
  if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
   {
    echo "connected successfully to database ".DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
  }

}
```

Output in the Chrome window: `connected successfully to database My_Database_Name`

As we see from above message, I am able to connect properly but still when I run the query I get the error:

```
(3/3) QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: SELECT * FROM TBL_Data WHERE ACTIVE_IND = 1 )
```

Added the `phpinfo();` in the controller and tried to hit the URL and got the following info related to the PDO:

`PDO support    enabled`

`PDO drivers    mysql, SQLite`

SQLSRV is not enabled here is this something which is causing the issue?

Comment: Did you install the `php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll` extension?

Comment: Yes I have added them to php.ini file, I wrote simple Connection testing PHP file and tested using WAMP  and I am able to connect using WAMP but using Laravel I am not able to connect. 
 Following are the sqlsrv files I have in php.ini file
 `extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll`

Comment: Gus can anyone help in this issue?
I am still getting the error, I tried re installing the SQL Server Express edition 2014 hoping it was something with the TCP/IP port issue but still no luck, Please provide some advice.

Comment: Put `phpinfo();` in your controller and visit the page: Is there a `pdo_sqlsrv` section?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Added the phpinfo(); in the controller and tried to hit that URL and got the PDO info but there is no mention of SQLSRV, (I have added the observation in the above question at the bottom, please check). could this something causing the issue? if so how to resolve this?

Comment: Please post the `extension=` lines from your `php.ini` file. Does `phpinfo()` use the `php.ini` file where you added the extensions ("Loaded Configuration File")?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Actually this worked, I replaced all of my `Extension` with my another `php.ini` file extension which was working with Laravel. I have posted the same below in the answer. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Again I am facing the same issue here. I tried adding the `phpinfo();` as mentioned by you in earlier comments and I am not able to find the `pdo_sqlsrv` section there. is there anything I am doing wrong please provide your thoughts. I have normal SQL Server query running properly without any issues.

Comment: Did you modify the `php.ini` file that `phpinfo()` shows under "Loaded Configuration File"?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I have modified the `php.ini` file in the PHP folder of the WAMP and added some of the `EXTENSION` to it so that it can connect to SQL Server. I have the `EXTENSION` which are mentioned in the 2nd Answer of this post. With those extensions, the Wamp was working fine and connecting to the SQL Server using Laravel so I used the same. I did not make any changes apart from this. I have made the changes to `php.ini` file which we get from WAMP directly, in my `LOADED CONFIGURATION FILE` the path is `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.ini` but I am not exactly sure if both `php.ini` sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was finally able to figure out the issue, Posting the same so it will help someone who has struck for days and ripping their hair out to find the solution.

1. Make sure you have given proper port in the Laravel while connection and its same as the one `SQL Server Configuration Manager` TCP/IP.
2. Make sure your TCP/IP is Enabled in `SQL Server Configuration Manager`.
3. I had some `Extension` which were missing in my `php.ini` file so I copy pasted these extension on to my `php.ini` file in the PHP of WAMP.

   extension=php_bz2.dll

   extension=php_curl.dll

   extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

   extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

   extension=php_com_dotnet.dll

   ;extension=php_enchant.dll

   extension=php_fileinfo.dll

   ;extension=php_ftp.dll

   extension=php_gd2.dll

   extension=php_gettext.dll

   extension=php_gmp.dll

   extension=php_intl.dll

   extension=php_imap.dll

   ;extension=php_interbase.dll

   extension=php_ldap.dll

   extension=php_mbstring.dll

   extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it

   extension=php_mysqli.dll

   extension=php_odbc.dll

   extension=php_openssl.dll

   ;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll

   extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

   ;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll

   ;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client

   extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll

   ;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll

   extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll

   ;extension=php_pgsql.dll

   ;extension=php_phpdbg_webhelper.dll

   ;extension=php_shmop.dll
4. Every time you change something in the `.env` file in the Laravel, you need to refresh it otherwise it will still use the old data which you have provided.

   `php artisan config:clear`

   `php artisan config:cache`
5. Restart the WAMP Server and the Laravel server `php artisan server`
6. My .env file in the Laravel:

   DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv

   DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

   DB_PORT=1433

   DB_DATABASE=DataBase_Name

   DB_USERNAME=sa

   DB_PASSWORD=MyPass

Hopefully this should work for you guys, Otherwise all the best and try to find the resolution and please let me also know.

Answer (score 2):

`This did NOT work for me but may work for some people hence posting this answer, hope this will be helpful`

I tried to change the port number for SQL Server still this one did not work, If anyone wants to try they can try this and see if this one will work.

`The issue was with MS-SQL Server 2012 Express didn't have port 1433 in the SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > TCP/IP > Properties> TCP Port was BLANK! Just type 1433 and restart the services and BAM!! Like Magic!`

Answer (score 0):

Check the `php.ini` file in the following location `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.35\php.ini` and add the following extension if it's not already present.

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

This will also resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but here is a docker file for PHP + SqlServer

```
FROM php:7.4.4-fpm-alpine as base

COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/bin/

RUN install-php-extensions sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

# Sql server necessary additions
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.apk \
    && curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.5.1.2-1_amd64.apk \
    && apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql17_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.apk \
    && apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools_17.5.1.2-1_amd64.apk
# Fix for sql server
ENV LC_ALL=C
```